# How to change component's state outside the component?

Tags: reactjs

In following lines I'll describe how I managed to create more cleaner and abstract approach to manage handling (not only) onChange in my code.

Later I came across this pattern:

```
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {...}

  handleText1Change = (e) =>
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      text1: e.target.value
    }))

  handleText2Change = (e) =>
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      text2: e.target.value
    }))

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleText1Change}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleText2Change}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It's pretty annoying to write a handling function per each input in a component and it roughly violates a **DRY principle** (don't repeat yourself). So I refactored it and got following:

```
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {...}

  handleInputChange = (value, property) =>
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      [property]: value
    }))

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e.target.value, 'text1')}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e.target.value, 'text2')}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Much cleaner and more reusable. But what if I need the same functionality in couple of other components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A similar approach, but you can also bind the utility function to the component instance in the constructor to avoid having to pass in `this` as an argument. You can also use a closure in `handleInputChange` to make its usage a little more succinct:

```
function handleInputChange (property) {
  return (e) => {
    this.setState({ [property]: e.target.value })
  }
}

class A extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleInputChange = handleInputChange.bind(this)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleInputChange('text1')} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with passing reference on *this*:

```
const handleInputChange = (value, property, _this) =>
  _this.setState(prevState => ({
    [property]: value
  }))

class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {...}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={e => handleInputChange(e.target.value, 'text1', this)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class B extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {...}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={e => handleInputChange(e.target.value, 'text2', this)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What do you think of this approach? How do you handle similar patterns in your code?